# "./postinstall" failed with return code [Timeout]

Tags: python, django, dotcloud

when i run 'dotcloud push traing'... running postinstall script take a long time and get error below.
I created a new account. 
cd to project and run command: 'dotcloud create training' and 'dotcloud push training' but nothing change.
anyone can help me?plz

```
Running postinstall script...
ERROR: deployment aborted due to unexpected command result: "./postinstall" failed with return code [Timeout]
```

postinstall

```
#!/bin/sh
#python createdb.py
python training/manage.py syncdb --noinput
python mkadmin.py
mkdir -p /home/dotcloud/data/media /home/dotcloud/volatile/static
python training/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==1.4
PIL==1.1.7
```

Comment: Have you installed and running DB ?

Comment: One thing you can do is add echo's to your post install so that in your logs you can see where it is getting hung, and then hopefully it will narrow down what is causing the timeout. Add one at the beginning of the postinstall, at the end and in between each command. If it is getting to the end, then it might be something out of your control, and you should contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your postinstall. It may help with locating the error (expanding on Ken's advice):

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -e makes the script exit on the first error
set -e
# set -x will add debug trace information to all of your commands
set -x

echo "$0 starting"

#python createdb.py

python training/manage.py syncdb --noinput
python mkadmin.py
mkdir -p /home/dotcloud/data/media /home/dotcloud/volatile/static
python training/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

echo "$0 complete"
```

More debugging info available at http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Answer (score 0):

Any error messages like "./postinstall failed with return code" means that there is a problem with your postinstall script.

In order to debug postinstall executions easily on dotCloud, you can do the following:

Let's assume that your app is "ramen" and your service is "www".

```
$ dotcloud -A ramen run www
> ~/current/postinstall
```

It'll re-execute the postinstall but from your session this time, so you'll be able to easily update the postinstall code and re-run it without having to push again and again.

Once you found the root cause, fix it locally and repush your application.